# jQuery Accordian that needs to open / close with tick boxes, and stay open if box is ticked

Tags: jquery, accordion

Little help needed if possible. I think I'm close just can't quite figure it out. Basically as the title says, I need to have a few tickboxes, if a box is ticked an accordion effect will kick in and reveal a textarea.

If the box is ticked, I need the accordion to stay open.

If the box is then un-ticked, I need the accordion to close up.

HTML
`
                                Solid Foundations (The Wheel)

Where you are fully compliant no further comment is necessary. Where you are not yet fully compliant please provide more information.

```
                        <div class="CheckButton two">
                            <label><input type="checkbox" />Getting to Grips With Governance (The Wheel)</label>                        
                        </div><!--checkButton-->
                        <div class="TextareaAccordion two">
                            <p><span class="helptext">Where you are fully compliant no further comment is necessary. Where you are not yet fully compliant please provide more information.</span></p>
                            <textarea name="" cols="10" rows="3" id="explanatorytext"></textarea>
                        </div>

                        <div class="CheckButton three">
                            <label><input type="checkbox" />Reducing the Risk (The Wheel)</label>                       
                        </div><!--checkButton-->
                        <div class="TextareaAccordion three">
                            <p><span class="helptext">Where you are fully compliant no further comment is necessary. Where you are not yet fully compliant please provide more information.</span></p>
                            <textarea name="" cols="10" rows="3" id="explanatorytext"></textarea>
                        </div>`
```

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                    $(document).ready(function() {
                        //ACCORDION BUTTON ACTION (ON CLICK DO THE FOLLOWING)
                        $('.CheckButton.one, .CheckButton.two, .CheckButton.three, .CheckButton.four, .CheckButton.five, .CheckButton.six, .CheckButton.seven, .CheckButton.eight, .CheckButton.nine').click(function() {

                        if($(this).next().is(':hidden') == true) {
                        //ADD THE ON CLASS TO THE BUTTON
                        $(this).addClass('on');
                        //OPEN THE SLIDE
                        $(this).next().slideDown('normal');
                        } 

                    });




                    /**CLOSES ALL S ON PAGE LOAD**/
                    $('.TextareaAccordion.one, .TextareaAccordion.two, .TextareaAccordion.three, .TextareaAccordion.four, .TextareaAccordion.five, .TextareaAccordion.six, .TextareaAccordion.seven, .TextareaAccordion.eight, .TextareaAccordion.nine').hide();});
                </script>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I would take this out:

```
$('.TextareaAccordion.one, .TextareaAccordion.two, .TextareaAccordion.three, .TextareaAccordion.four, .TextareaAccordion.five, .TextareaAccordion.six, .TextareaAccordion.seven, .TextareaAccordion.eight, .TextareaAccordion.nine').hide();
```

I would simply use CSS to hide those `div` tags.

Secondly, you don't have to reference each of them individually, `$('.TextareaAccordion').hide();` would suffice.

Here is my solution: http://jsbin.com/egude4/22/edit

Comment: Hi Anriëtte, thanks for your reply. well, I think I figured it out. Basically each checkbox with the hidden textarea has to be it's own separate accordion. The reason for this is that if one is open, and then another is clicked, it closes the previous one. If each one is it's own separate accordion, then they can all be open or all be closed if needs be.

Comment: Anriëtte Combrink's solution works but the tick boxes / labels are a bit buggy? The tickbox doesn't always stay ticked.